# Why does my site change my CSS for me?

Tags: css, drupal, jssor

I have jssor slideshow module installed on my drupal 8 site.  I am trying to have the arrows on the slides to navigate the slideshow. The problem is something is adding

```
display: none;
```

to my arrows.  When I remove the the line in the terminal the arrow appears but when I put my mouse back on the page out of the terminal window the arrow disappears and the

```
display: none;
```

line is back.

What causes this and how can I stop it?

Comment: Your browser's web inspector will tell you what set a particular CSS rule.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Are you sure it's not the browser you're using?  Perhaps you will have to swap style sheets to allow for different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `display: block !important;` ? I often have to use the `!important` to stop my CSS being overridden by other modules.

The preferred method of resolving this kind of issue is to ensure that the CSS files are being loaded in the correct order (it is Cascading Style Script after all). However in this instance, and as is often the case with CMS type sites (or those where you don't have access to changing the loading order of the CSS files), the `!important` declaration is the solution.

Comment: nailed it.  I dont know why I didn't think of that

Comment: Trust me, when I discovered this it changed my world! Especially when you're using a modular system with many many CSS files. Glad it worked :)