# How to avoid third party CSS to affect current CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my site, I'm changing a style of DIV using Jquery/Javascript. The same DIV  style is later changed by third party js library. Is there a way to avoid the third party style changes.
I'm not allowed to use CSS to override, as CSS is also written by different source.

Comment: you should add the Vendor CSS first and then your own CSS.

Comment: It depends what the 3rd party changes are and how they're implemented, on a selector basis.  For example, if they apply a style to `.somediv` then you can use the selector `div.somediv` as it's more specific, so yours would hold more weight and be applied.  You could also just slap `!important` after everything, but that's not a nice solution.

Comment: you can style it with it's id. as id's have highest priority. so overriding it is not quite possible without using `!important` css hack.

Comment: Can you show some HTML and wanted CSS?

Comment: This is the same problem as was resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31750963/4952851

Comment: If the third party library changes the style attribute of the div rather than the page's stylesheet, there is not much you can do. Try to insert your own routine after the third party one.

Comment: [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM) comes to mind, but it's still very poorly supported in today's browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your css
//// here use id and !important(hack)
#id1{ 
 color: blue !important;
}

// third party css class
.class1{
 color: red;
}

// your element
<input type="text" class="class1" id="id1"/>
```

Output:
The color will be blue. Your css will win.

Read more about Specificity in css to understand better.

Note: Id is more specific than class.