# Css class is overridden by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text

I am using [BigText](https://github.com/chunksnbits/jquery-quickfit) library to make some text to fit into div. 
My Problem is that the additional style I applied to the text is override and ignored. For example text-align:left is not working anymore. And the list points are not shown. How can I get the functionality of the script and add the css class?

I am calling the bigText function like that:

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() { 
        $(".area_competences_text").bigText();
    });

    $(window).trigger('resize');    
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="area_competences_text">    
    <ul>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li>
        <li>SOME TEXT</li> 
    </ul>                               
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.area_competences_text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: you can reach this by using !important on your css

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750839/why-does-my-site-change-my-css-for-me/31750963#31750963

Comment: Avoid using !important tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add !important

```
.area_competences_text {
    text-align: left !important;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this without using css like below:

```
$(function() {
        $(window).on('resize', function() { 
            $(".area_competences_text").bigText();
            $(".area_competences_text").css("text-align","left")
                                       .css("padding","5%");
        });
            $(window).trigger('resize');    
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do was to add a ID or another class to the div:

**EX#1**

## HTML

```
<div class="area_competences_text" id="my_id"> 

                                <ul>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li> 
                                </ul>  

</div>
```

## CSS

```
#my_id {
    text-align: left !important;
    padding-top: 5% !important;
    padding-left: 5% !important;
    padding-right: 5% !important;
    padding-bottom: 5% !important;
}
```

**EX#2**

## HTML

```
<div class="area_competences_text second_class"> 

                                <ul>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li>
                                   <li>SOME TEXT</li> 
                                </ul>  

</div>
```

## CSS

```
.area_competences_text.second_class {
    text-align: left !important;
    padding-top: 5% !important;
    padding-left: 5% !important;
    padding-right: 5% !important;
    padding-bottom: 5% !important;
}
```

When you are adding ID or another class and refer to both of classes, you then are more specific about what needs to be styled.

Comment: This will not work as jquery adds the styling inline, which overrides any css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important` to a setting to not let it be overridden:

```
.area_competences_text {
    text-align: left !important;
etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important like below:

```
.area_competences_text {
    text-align: left !important;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="area_competences_text" style="text-align: left !important;">
...
</div>
```